# Kitchen faucet hot water slows to a trickle

Tags: plumbing, water

When I open  the hot water of my kitchen faucet it flows at normal pressure, then after 1 minute or more it slows to a small drizzle, then less water, then a single tiny stream of water.

I turn it off, wait a few seconds, turn it back on and again it at   normal pressure,  then less and less.
I can repeat this behavior over and over.

This only happens to my kitchen faucet.
My dishwasher does not have an issue.

Comment: Is the problem only on the hot water side? Usually this indicates a faulty cartridge. You should also [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you can best use this site.

Comment: If your supply line is flexible type with a kink in it this will sometimes get worse as the tube warms up

Comment: This could quite likely be associated with (defective) temperature control features in some higher-end faucets, or with the flex-hoses that connect them to water supply.  Can you post the faucet model or a photo of it and of the connections?